# How to turn a table or matrix into a (flat) list in J

Tags: list, matrix, j

I know how to reshape a list into a table. But how do I turn a table into a list or uni- dimensional array.

```
my_list=:3 4 $i.12

0 1  2  3
4 5  6  7
8 9 10 11
```

And is it better to perform operations on lists or tables or is there no difference (in terms of performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`, y` (ravel) is what you need:

```
    , my_list
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

There is no performance difference for operations where the shape of the data does not matter, f.e. `1 + my_list` and `1 + , my_list`. Also reshaping is free (if no padding is involved), because internally the atoms are always saved as a flat list with its corresponding shape. `my_list` could be understood as the tuple of the lists `data: 0…11` and `shape: 3 4`, while `, my_list` would be `data: 0…11` and `shape: 12`.